# Trying to console log in foreach callback function

Tags: javascript

How do can I console.log inside of foreach callback function. I am creating a html description list and iterating over a list of javascript objects to append to the dl and add buttons to the dd's. My goal is to show the questions as dt's and hide/show the answers with the dd buttons. In an attempt to better understand and figure out how I'm going to do this I am trying to console the id's of each button. Thank you. [Here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNgNmOw?editors=1010) is a link to the codepen.

```
const questions = [
  {
    statement: "2+2?",
    answer: "2+2 = 4"
  },
  {
    statement: "In which year did Christopher Columbus discover America?",
    answer: "1492"
  },
  {
    statement:
      "What occurs twice in a lifetime, but once in every year, twice in a week but never in a day?",
    answer: "The E letter"
  }
];


const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const dl = document.createElement('dl');
for (const question of questions) {
  const dt = document.createElement('dt');
  const dd = document.createElement('dd');
  dt.innerText = question.statement;
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  dd.innerHTML = "<button>Show answer</button>";
  dd.id = question.answer;
  dl.appendChild(dt);
  dl.appendChild(dd);
  console.log(dd);
  dl.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
content.appendChild(dl);

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(function(b){
  console.log(b.getAttribute("id"));
});
```

Comment: Are you referring to this `console.log(b.getAttribute("id"));` part and why you're not seeing the ids in the console? You're assigning ids to the `dd` elements (at `dd.id = question.answer;`) so you need to select the `dd` elements instead of the buttons to see their ids, like `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('dd');`

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the button elements which does not have the attribute id. You have to select the dd elements in order to access their ids.

You can do this by using

```
document.querySelectorAll('dd');
```

instead of using

```
document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

Comment: You can check updated version of your code here: https://codepen.io/czaftan/pen/WNbNVbx?editors=1010#anon-signup

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print the querySelectorAll it would be something like the below , I have just updated the snippet to print the components using the foreach . `buttons.forEach(p => console.log(p));`

Output :

```
"<dd id='2+2 = 4'><button>Show answer</button></dd>"
"<dd id='1492'><button>Show answer</button></dd>"
"<dd id='The E letter'><button>Show answer</button></dd>"
"<button>Show answer</button>"
"<button>Show answer</button>"
"<button>Show answer</button>"
```